# Discrete Log Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography, maple

I've been given this key for an elliptic curve crypto -system:

A:=4569782456273849

B:=74578265973825694738

p:=164516845864567592349187678956932587156973824569837657473

So the EC group is G:=[A,B,p]

The two points from the group are
g:=[48563875638, 59953686086232350377099851919349194342354278013502470154]

b:=[94505880155199340954270580844602804762931528214881553767, 125066642042178110526107700200751399553923146040555130047]

The tolerance parameter is t:=49.

The ciphertext is:

e:=[93639666479598242411823008371484237433314325218557988665, 52243374701368396864838008344430211295076041963702946225]

y:=[141014893828387250204699736658837464619673828728217488819, 54503942085017207420659567572818024668020348976893792817]

I need to decrypt the messsage and determine the private key "x" for which $b=g^x$.

The problem is I can't calculate the group order for G, so I can't use an HPS attack. I think that eliminates Pollard-Rho and Baby Step attacks as well.

Any ideas for a strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I find with Sage that the order of the group is
$2^2 * 3 * 179 * 769 * 99597802815676113473680829865485023921426165084723$

So you can use Pohlig–Hellman to reduce the discrete log a little bit but not so much.